# Broken :body Element using clj-http.client

Tags: clojure

i am trying to retrieve a website with Clojure and the clj-http library.
I wanted to start slow with a simple example:

```
(:body (client/get (str "http://www.google.com") {:as :clojure}))
```

As far as i understand the behaviour of the library, this call should return the body of the website but all it returns is `<!doctype`.

When i try to call

```
(:body (client/get (str "http://www.google.com") {:as :json}))
```

i even get an exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60))
```

I can not imagine the library to be broken but also i am not able to see an obvious error in my call. Has anybody of you experienced this behaviour?

Comment: Probably the problem is that Google doesn't return clojure or json data, just HTML...

Comment: You are right, after reading the other answers i just misunderstood the :as option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the http response body as a string you can use the following:

```
(:body (client/get "http://www.google.com"))
```

The `:as` entry in the `{:as :clojure}` options is [output-coercion](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http#output-coercion), and is trying to convert the HTML body, from google.com, into a Clojure data structure. This will fail unless the response body actually contains Clojure code.

If you are trying to parse the HTML response, you might need to look into an additional library, like [Enlive](https://github.com/cgrand/enlive/).

Comment: Enlive was my first approach but i could not manage to set an user-agent and so google denied access. I definitely agree this would be much more elegant. Thank you for pointing out the correct useage of :as!

Comment: You can pass Enlive the HTML string and still have it parse and transform it if you need that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're querying a URL that is not returning the data type you're coercing the result to.

For instance if you try with `http://ip.jsontest.com/` this url which returns a proper json:

```
 (require '[clj-http.client :as client])
 (client/get "http://ip.jsontest.com/" {:as :json})
 => {:trace-redirects ["http://ip.jsontest.com/"], :request-time 1153, 
     :status 200, 
     :headers {"access-control-allow-origin" "*", "content-type" "application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1", "date" "Tue, 22 Oct 2013 19:50:36 GMT", "server" "Google Frontend", "cache-control" "private", "alternate-protocol" "80:quic,80:quic", "connection" "close"}, :body {:ip "186.54.233.167"}}
```

Response is properly parsed.

Checking the response `body` you can easily see there's a `json` indeed there:

```
(:body (client/get "http://ip.jsontest.com/"))
=> "{\"ip\": \"186.54.233.167\"}\n"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you are right. I indeed misunderstood the behaviour.